# Cannot use a Namespaced Class inside another namespace in PHP

Tags: php, namespaces

I am still having trouble with PHP5 Namespaces.

I have a namespace called `Project` and I am trying to access a class called `registry` inside of this `Project` namespace that has a namespace of `Library` so at the top of the file that is a `Project` namespace I use this line `use Library\Registry;`

`Registry` class is inside the `Library` Namespace

This should work but it doesn't, instead the ONLY way to access my `registry` class inside this `Project` namespace is to use this

```
$this->registry = new \Library\Registry;
```

I want to be able to use this instead...

```
$this->registry = new Registry;
```

That was the whole reason of using

```
use Library\Registry;
```

at the top of the `Project` namespace file

---

Below I have 3 small example scripts in a folder structure like this.
`Library/registry.class.php` a class in my Library folder
`Controller/controller.class.php` and class in my Controller directory
`Controller/testing.php` a test file to run the script.

**E:\Library\Registry.class.php file**

```
<?php
namespace Library
{
    class Registry
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            echo 'Registry.class.php Constructor was ran';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**E:\Controller\Controller.class.php file**

```
<?php
use Library\Registry;

namespace Project
{
    class Controller
    {
        public $registry;

        function __construct()
        {
            include('E:\Library\Registry.class.php');

            // This is where my trouble is
            // to make it work currently I have to use
            //  $this->registry = new /Library/Registry;
            // But I want to be able to use it like below and that is why
            // I have the `use Library\Registry;` at the top
            $this->registry = new Registry;
        }

        function show()
        {
            $this->registry;
            echo '<br>Registry was ran inside testcontroller.php<br>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**E:\Controller\testing.php file**

```
<?php
use Project\Controller;

include('testcontroller.php');

$controller = new Controller();
$controller->show();

?>
```

I get this error...

```
Fatal error: Class 'Project\Registry' not found in PATH to file
```

unless I use this below  on the controller.class.php file

```
$this->registry = new \MyLibrary\Registry;
```

Because in that file at the top I have `use Library\Registry;` I should be able to access it like this...

```
$this->registry = new Registry;
```

Please help me get it where I can use it like that instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
use Library\Registry;

namespace Project
{
```

I *believe* that's the wrong way round: you're `use`ing `Library\Registry` in the global namespace, and then opening the `Project` namespace.

Put the `use` statement *inside* the namespace you want to import it into.

```
namespace Project
{
    use Library\Registry;
```

Comment: Actually the docs say you cannot do that, it trows a fatal error if you use the `use` after the namespace is set.  In my example it caused this `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS, expecting ',' or ';' in E:\Controller\controller.class.php on line 8`

Comment: @jasondavis No, that was because I forgot to put the semicolon at the end of the statement. Try it with the version I edited. (Incidentally, that should have been fairly obvious from the error...)

Comment: You're right I should of spotted that.  It seems to be working, is this the way it should always be done?  After the namespace declaration?  Everytime I think I fully got it with these namespaces, something pops up that doesn't work, working with multiple namespaces is where my trouble starts I should say.  Thanks for your help.  When looking at C# projects they do it the other way around so I think that adds to the confusion

Comment: Yes, you always need to import into a namespace or into the global scope. [You can see some more information about this in the manual.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

Answer (score 2):

You need to import your `Registry` class inside `Project` namespace, because you need em there, not in global scope.

```
<?php   
namespace Project
{
    use Library\Registry;

    class Controller
    {
        public $registry;

        function __construct()
        {
            include('E:\Library\Registry.class.php');

            // This is where my trouble is
            // to make it work currently I have to use
            //  $this->registry = new /Library/Registry;
            // But I want to be able to use it like below and that is why
            // I have the `use Library\Registry;` at the top
            $this->registry = new Registry;
        }

        function show()
        {
            $this->registry;
            echo '<br>Registry was ran inside testcontroller.php<br>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add:
use \Library\Registry;

at top of your script under the namespace declaration

Then you can just say:

$registry = new Registry;

inside your class

By the way your class declaration is all wrong. You should not wrap your namespace inside curly braces, namespace is not a function.

This is how it should be. Also make sure the class declaration of Library\Registry is already included by either using include('/path/to/registry.php'); or using autoloader

```
namespace Project;
```

include('E:\Library\Registry.class.php');

```
use \Library\Registry;

    class Controller
    {
        public $registry;

        function __construct()
        {


            // This is where my trouble is
            // to make it work currently I have to use
            //  $this->registry = new /Library/Registry;
            // But I want to be able to use it like below and that is why
            // I have the `use Library\Registry;` at the top
            $this->registry = new Registry;
        }

        function show()
        {
            $this->registry;
            echo '<br>Registry was ran inside testcontroller.php<br>';
        }
    }
```

Enjoy

Comment: Dont you see I already have that in controller.class.php file

Comment: There's nothing wrong with enclosing your namespace in curly brackets. [See the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definitionmultiple.php)

Comment: Sorry, I really did not know about wrapping namespace in braces, just never seen anyone doing it this way.

Comment: @Dmitri Snytkine sorry as well I think I read your answer wrong the first time, and you do provide the correct answer now.  On another note,  I really like the project you have done, the Q&A one, perhaps I could send you an email about namespaces and the how you did them in your project if you don't mind?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php namespace Project;
    require_once 'your registry class file';
    use \Library\Registry as Registry;
```

Now you will be able to use...

```
    $this->registry = new Registry;
```